# Фильтр SVG: шириной 100% высотой 100% не полностью обрабатывает изображение

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-filter

У меня есть простой фильтр SVG. Если вы щелкните на примере ниже, этот фильтр появится / исчезнет:

```js
var image = document.querySelector('image');

var url = 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/202/200/200.jpg?hmac=eGzhW5P2k0gzjc76Tk5T9lOfvn30h3YHuw5jGnBUY4Y';

image.setAttribute('xlink:href', url);

window.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var filter = image.getAttribute('filter')
    ? ''
    : 'url(#blur)';
  image.setAttribute('filter', filter);
})
```

```css
image {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width='200' height='200'>
  <filter id='blur' width='100%' height='100%'>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='2' result='blur' />
  </filter>
  <image x='0' width='200px' height='200px' xlink:href='' id='svg-image' filter='url(#blur)'  />
</svg>
```

Я бы хотел, чтобы отфильтрованное изображение было того же размера, что и нефильтрованное. Кто-нибудь знает, как я могу это сделать?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SVG Filter: width 100% height 100% does not cover image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64540567/7394871) от участника  [@duhaime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1727392/duhaime).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64540567/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо установить начальный размер с помощью атрибутов x и y следующим образом.

```
<filter id='blur' x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%'>
```

```js
var image = document.querySelector('image');

var url = 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/202/200/200.jpg?hmac=eGzhW5P2k0gzjc76Tk5T9lOfvn30h3YHuw5jGnBUY4Y';

image.setAttribute('xlink:href', url);

window.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var filter = image.getAttribute('filter')
    ? ''
    : 'url(#blur)';
  image.setAttribute('filter', filter);
})
```

```css
image {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width='200' height='200'>
  <filter id='blur' x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%'>
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='2' result='blur' />
  </filter>
  <image x='0' width='200px' height='200px' xlink:href='' id='svg-image' filter='url(#blur)'  />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64540909/7394871) от участника  [@Derek.W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8202850/derek-w).</sub>